# Why does my code not retrieve/display the PDO record set?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo, prepared-statement

Using the code below, I get the error, **"Call to undefined method stdClass::fetchObject()"**.

```
function getProdDetails2SaveInInvoice($data) {

    global $dbh;

    try {
        $sth=$dbh->prepare("
        SELECT
            AES_DECRYPT('alt_id', ?),
            AES_DECRYPT('prod_name', ?),
            AES_DECRYPT('prod_desc', ?)
         FROM
            products
        WHERE
        prod_id = ?
    ");

        $sth->execute($data);
        $rs = $sth->query(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        return $rs;
    }

    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo  "Something went wrong. Please report this error.\n";
        file_put_contents(
            $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/PDOErrors.txt",
            "\n\nScript name : ".SCRIPT."\nFunction name : ".__FUNCTION__."\n".
            $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);

        throw new failedTransaction();
    }
}

$data = array(
    DBKEY,                  /* field 1                  */
    DBKEY,                  /* field 2                  */
    DBKEY,                  /* field 3                  */
    $prodid             /* comparison               */
);
$rs = getProdDetails2SaveInInvoice($data);

while ($row = $rs->fetchObject()) {
    echo $row->prod_name;
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work and returns the error mentioned above.

I can confirm that the $dbh database connection is working as it's the same connection working for the inserts and updates. Thanks.

### UPDATE

This is how I've amended my code based on the suggestions below, but I'm still getting nothing returned:

```
try {
    $dbh    = new PDO("mysql:host=".CO_DB_HOST.";dbname=".CO_DB_NAME, CO_DB_UNAME, CO_DB_PWORD);

    $dbh    ->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

function getProdDetails2SaveInInvoice($data) {

    global $dbh;

    try {
        $sth=$dbh->prepare("
        SELECT
            AES_DECRYPT('alt_id', ?),
            AES_DECRYPT('prod_name', ?),
            AES_DECRYPT('prod_desc', ?)
         FROM
            products
        WHERE
            prod_id = ?
    ");

        $sth->execute($data);

        while ($row = $sth->fetchObject()) {
            // PROCESS ROW
            $rs = array($row->alt_id, $row->prod_name, $row->prod_desc);
        }
        return $rs;
    }

    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo  "Something went wrong. Please report this error.\n";
        file_put_contents(
            $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/PDOErrors.txt",
            "\n\nScript name : ".SCRIPT."\nFunction name : ".__FUNCTION__."\n".
            $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);

        throw new failedTransaction();
    }
}

// Fetch additional info from invoice_products.
$data = array(
    DBKEY,                  /* field 1                  */
    DBKEY,                  /* field 2                  */
    DBKEY,                  /* field 3                  */
    $prodid                 /* comparison               */
);
$rs = getProdDetails2SaveInInvoice($data);

print_r($rs);
```

If I hardcode the 'where' argument (19), it still does not retrieve the result. Ideally I think I should retrieve the result in an object so that it can be streamed, but right now, I'd be happy even if it came in a box!

The data is definitely existing in the database and can be pulled using a traditional query.

This is the output of the print_r($rs):

Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => 
    [2] => 
)

Comment: hint: `FETCH_ASSOC` returns ..... ? You are trying to retrieve ..... ?

Comment: Sorry @itachi I only just saw your comment. Honestly I'm trying to retrieve anything right now. If I can find at least one way to retrieve something, then I'll probably try to hone what I'm retrieving into an object, because I believe that's kinder to server resources than arrays for large resultsets. Please can elaborate on your point regarding 'FETCH_ASSOC'? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should loop over the prepared statement, and not call `query` on the prepared statement. Basic usage of prepared statements is as follows:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("YOUR QUERY");
$sth->execute();
$results = array();
while ($row = $sth->fetchObject()) {
    $results[] = array(
        'alt_id' => $row->alt_id,
        'prod_name' => $row->prod_name,
        'prod_desc' => $row->prod_desc
    );
}

return $result;
```

As an alternative you could also use `$sth->fetchAll()` which returns an array with all rows that are the result of your query, see [PDOStatement::fetchAll()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php).

Comment: Thanks Jan-Henk. That's a nuisance! So what would be the best way to extract the retrieved data for use in follow-on queries? I need to somehow pass it back to the main code where I can use the result in a variety of ways outside of the function.

Comment: I think I'm thinking to do this by looping through the results in the while statement adding them to an array, which I'll then return to the main code, but I'm worried that doing that with some of my other queries might not work because of the size of the result sets. Arrays need to be stored in server memory, while objects can be streamed, but can someone show me how to get the results into an object which I can pass back in the return? Thanks.

Comment: I updated my answer. I would not optimize for memory usage unless you actually run into problems.